# QlikSense Field selectValues API - not working when the field name is date datatype in mashup application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, qliksense

Issue in Qliksense SelectValues Field API when the field is Date format

Hi ,

Just to provide you background - We have multiple qlik apps opened in our web application and when the user makes the selections in primary app - we apply the common selection across all the apps opened. We have this strange issue with fields that are tagged as Date in the datamodel. Please check below example.

Version : June 2020 Patch 7 v13.82.15

I have issue with selectValues Field API when the field is in Date format.

**1. Scenario 1 - Field : Month_Year is date datatype:**

Let say, I have val array in which I have selected values of the date type field "Month_Year".

```
Var FieldName = "Month_Year";  // field in datamodel script :  Date#(Month_Year,'MMM YYYY') AS Month_Year

var valArray[]= {
                 0:"Jan 2020"
                 1:"Feb 2020"
                 2:"Mar 2020"
                 }

app.Field(FieldName ).selectValues(valArray);
```

it is not selecting the value in desired "app" because the FieldName = Month_Year is derived as Date#(Month_Year,'MMM YYYY').

**2. Scenario 2 - Field : Month_Year is TEXT() string datatype:**

Let say, I have val array in which I have selected values of the text/string type field "Month_Year".

```
Var FieldName = "Month_Year";  // field in datamodel script :  Text(Month_Year) AS Month_Year

var valArray[]= {
                  0:"Jan 2020"
                  1:"Feb 2020"
                  2:"Mar 2020"
                  }

app.Field(FieldName ).selectValues(valArray);
```

Now the same field is making the selections in the field if we bring the field as text(Month_Year) as Month_Year.

did anyone faced this issue in your mash up application?

Answer (score 0):

Thats because under the hood Qlik is storing the values in dual representation - number and text (especially for fields that are flagged as date). The actual value for `01/01/2020` is actually `43831` and its displayed as `01 Jan 2020` (or whatever is the date format). So when trying to select `Jan 2020` nothing is happening because such value do not exists.

When you "break" the dual representation (using the  `Text()` function) then the selection is working but potentially there can be performance implications (based on the data volume in the app mostly)

Have a look at the [dual()](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/qlikview/April2020/Subsystems/Client/Content/QV_QlikView/Scripting/FormattingFunctions/Dual.htm) function documentation for more info about this behaviour.

In order to select something in this case you'll have to find the underlying values or element numbers and select them.

Personally I'm creating temporary listbox for the required filed and when I have to select I'm finding the `qElemNumber` of the required values and then selecting them in the listbox

```js
// let values = ['array', 'of', 'values',  'to', 'select']

// create the session object
let sessionObj = await qDoc.createSessionObject(lbDef);

// get the layout so we can loop through the data pages
let layout = await sessionObj.getLayout();

// get the qElemNumber for the required values
// WARNING: if the field contains more than 1000 (i think) DISTINCT values then we'll have to loop through all the databased
let index = layout.field.qListObject.qDataPages[0].qMatrix.filter(function (m) {
  return values.indexOf(m[0].qText) > -1
}).map(function (e) {
  return e[0].qElemNumber
});

// perform the selection
let selection = await sessionObj.selectListObjectValues('/field/qListObjectDef', index, toggle);
```

I've used such approach [here](https://github.com/countnazgul/enigma-mixin/blob/6c715f52af1331e4dcb6930e05ad9bedffafb38b/src/mixins/doc/qSelections.js#L56)

Comment: Thank you Stefan ! I will have a look into it. For now we have changed that field as text() and making selections in other apps. It would have been too easy if we get equivalent number of each value in the same response like qNum in qSelections.qSelectedFieldSelectionInfo . I will also keep an eye on performance of the application. This master calendar table has around 2200 rows with distinct value of 36 in the mentioned field. Thank you again - This is a new approach I have not even thought of it.